# Rails - set POST request limit (file upload)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rack, carrierwave

I am building a file uploader for Rails, using [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave). I am pretty happy about it's API, except that I don't seem to be able to cut file uploads that exceed a limit on the fly.

I found [this plugin](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Validate-attachment-file-size) for validation, but the problem is that it happens **after** the upload is completed. It is completely unacceptable in my case, *as any user could take the site down by uploading a huge file*.

So, I figure that the way would be to use some Rack configuration or middleware that will limit POST body size as it receives. I am hosting on Heroku, as context.

*I am aware of https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct but it doesn't solve my issue as I have to resize first and discard the original large image.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty workaround is to use a javascript uploader and validate there. If that isn't good enough:

- If you switch your application server to [rainbows](http://rainbows.rubyforge.org), you can use a setting called [client_max_body_size](http://rainbows.rubyforge.org/Rainbows/Configurator.html).
- If you're using another application server, you're going to have to look for an equivalent setting (which may not exist), or come up with some kind of middleware (which may or may not be possible depending on your application server). If you write a clean middleware that does this, I imagine lots of people would be interested, since there doesn't appear to be one out there right now.
- If you weren't using heroku, you could use nginx's client_max_body_size setting, or whatever the equivalent is for apache.